# Is saying "five times greater" wrong?

Tags: word-choice

For general comparisons note the following<sup>[(1)](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect5&info0=5.24#zz5)</sup>:

> five times as great
>
> **not**
>
> five times greater

Is it wrong to say "*five times greater*"? The former sounds rather "*equal*" to me, means not more or fewer than five times  .

(1)*`http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect5&info0=5.24#zz5`*

Comment: In common usage, they're equivalent. However, if you consider that 2 is 'one time' greater than 1, then it would follow that 5x greater would mean a total of 6x 'as great'.

Comment: Uhh... it makes sense what you are saying. I see.

Comment: @Lawrence  I agree there's some ambiguity but many would interpret "Five times greater" as y = 5x  and not y = 5x + x.  In other words, "y is greater than x by a factor of 5".   If someone wanted to be specific, I would recommend a different expression or actual math.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that's why I started by saying that they're equivalent in common usage. The (5+1)x interpretation is awkward, but there are situations where either the context requires it, or where pedants (or tests) will object to the (more usual) 5x interpretation. I think it comes down to whether one treats *greater* in a multiplicative or additive sense. It's normally additive (0.5m greater than 1m = 1.5m), but *times* pushes it to a multiplicative sense.

Comment: Please note that the cited source is a *style* guide of the Government of Canada.  It represents stricter limitations than the English language in general requires.  The claim here is not that "five times greater" is grammatically wrong.  It's that "five times as great" is a clearer, less ambiguous, preferable *style*.  The Canadian government has a vested interest in making sure that legal documents published in both English and French represent the same unambiguous semantics in both languages.